# django-appengine server not starting

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I've been trying to use Django-appengine to write a small web app, but I am stuck on setting up the development server. I have followed the tutorial as best a human can, and I have modified the test app's app.yaml to include my app ID, but nothing more:

```
application: appidgoeshere
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

builtins:
- remote_api: on

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: djangoappengine/deferred/handler.py
  login: admin

- url: /_ah/stats/.*
  script: djangoappengine/appstats/ui.py

- url: /media/admin
  static_dir: django/contrib/admin/media
  expiration: '0'

- url: /.*
  script: djangoappengine/main/main.py
```

When I run `manage.py runserver`, or `manage.py remote shell`, I get a traceback similar to this (in particular, this is from `runserver`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Eclipse Projects\appnamehere\manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    import settings
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Eclipse Projects\appnamehere\settings.py", line 4, in <module>
    from djangoappengine.settings_base import *
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Eclipse Projects\appnamehere\djangoappengine\settings_base.py", line 6, in <module>
    setup_env()
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Eclipse Projects\appnamehere\djangoappengine\boot.py", line 65, in setup_env
    setup_project()
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Eclipse Projects\appnamehere\djangoappengine\boot.py", line 117, in setup_project
    from .utils import have_appserver, on_production_server
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Eclipse Projects\appnamehere\djangoappengine\utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    appconfig, unused = dev_appserver.LoadAppConfig(PROJECT_DIR, {})
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3489, in LoadAppConfig
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3344, in ReadAppConfig
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo_includes.py", line 47, in Parse
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo_includes.py", line 81, in _MergeBuiltinsIncludes
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo_includes.py", line 125, in _ResolveIncludes
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo_includes.py", line 177, in _ConvertBuiltinsToIncludes
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\builtins\__init__.py", line 88, in get_yaml_path

google.appengine.ext.builtins.InvalidBuiltinName: remote_api is not the name of a valid builtin handler.
Available handlers are:
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at this, and if you have any advice or need more information please ask. I'm new to this entire technology stack, so I may have missed something.

Comment: It sounds like you're running an old version of the SDK. Have you tried updating the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're running an old version of the SDK. Have you tried updating the SDK?

Comment: This was it! I installed the new SDK, but I did not delete a previous version on my disk. django-nonrel was finding and using it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing:

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

It looks just fine to me, but that is the specific error above.

Comment: I just tried it, and I receieve the same error except for the final line which now states `google.appengine.ext.builtins.InvalidBuiltinName: default is not the name of a valid builtin handler.
Available handlers are:`